# How can I configure linux to switch automatically between LAN and WLAN without using network-manager

Tags: networking

How can the following be done without using network-manager or another GUI-tool (for example by configuring `/etc/networking/interfaces` etc):

Automatically (and without delay) switch to LAN if available and back to WLAN if not LAN is available anymore.

If possible each time the same IP should be used (may be static, but it doesn't need to be).

My system is ubuntu 16.04.1.

Comment: It does this automatically: [NetworkManager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager)

Comment: Do you want to avoid the whole network-manager system entirely, not just its GUI frontend?

Comment: @ChristianTernus: Yes for this question I want to avoid the network-manager system entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without Network manager using bonding WiFi and Ethernet interfaces in active-backup mode . Do it as described in this article:  [Network bonding (wlan & eth) on linux ubuntu](http://www.lemmster.de/network-bonding-wlan-eth-on-linux-ubuntu.html)